# jquery: if (target) is child of ('.wrapper') then (do something)

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var target = $(this).attr("href");

if {target is child of ('.wrapper')} then (do something)
```

simple syntax? can someone show me the correct syntax here?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

```
if($(target).parents('.wrapper').length > 0) {
   //do something...
}
```

Comment: Small modification instead of $(target) use $(this) as target contains string.

Comment: Note that this tests that target is a direct child of wrapper.

Comment: @Chinmayee, the `href` is pointing to the actual `id` of the element that the OP wants to check, not `this`.

Comment: You should use closest instead of parents.

Comment: Better to check `.length > 0`.

Comment: @rahul 0 is a falsy value, though, so you don't really need to.

Comment: +1 because this helped me solved my "opposite" issues when I detected length == 0

Comment: @jantimon while there are **[significant differences between `.parents()` and `.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/#entry-longdesc)**, I think `.parents()` is what OP wanted here. Thanks for pointing it out though!

Comment: @Trojan In which case would `$(target).parents('.wrapper').length > 0` not return the same as `$(target).closest('.wrapper').length > 0`?

Comment: @jantimon It would, *except* if the target also had class `wrapper` (`.closest()` begins traversal at `target`, not its parent).

Comment: Note: "direct child" and "child" are synonymous. A "nested child" is a _descendent_ of `.wrapper`, and `.wrapper` is an _ancestor_ of "nested children".

Answer (score 39):

`.has()` is maybe the mose convenient syntax:

```
if( $('.wrapper').has($(target)) ) {
     // do something
}
```

Even more 'powerful' (in terms of performance) is `$.contains()`. So an ideal algorithm should look like:

```
var $wrapper =  $('.wrapper'),
    $target  =  $(this).attr('href');

if( $.contains($wrapper[0], $target[0]) ) {
    // do something
}
```

Reference: [.has()](http://api.jquery.com/has/), [$.contains()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/)

Comment: +1 for `$.contains()` which is explicitly described by jQuery API as "Check to see if a DOM element is a descendant of another DOM element."

Comment: I would not recommend using `.has()` as described, because it does not return a boolean like you would expect. Instead, it filters the original set of DOM elements and returns a new jQuery object. ("Description: Reduce the set of matched elements to those that have a descendant that matches the selector or DOM element.") So although it _does_ produce the correct result in this case, I think the return value is unintuitive and may give you headaches if you assume it returns a boolean.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a tidier way: bind it as a jQuery plugin. You might find it be easier to understand and use.

```
   $.fn.isChildOf = function(element)
{
    return $(element).has(this).length > 0;
}
```

Usage:

```
    if ( $('.target').isChildOf('.wrapper') ) {
      //do all the things.
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use [parent](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) or [parents](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) method like in the links

http://jsfiddle.net/6BX9n/

http://jsfiddle.net/6BX9n/1/

Answer (score 2):

Small change to Jacob's code, if the child is deeper than one level in.

```
if($(target).parents('.wrapper').length) {
   //do something...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old post, but it could be useful for someone.
It seems to me that in many cases using .closest() would have better performance:

```
if ($(target).closest('.wrapper').length){
    // your code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
    </div>
 </div>


$(".child").is(".parent .child")
```

Comment: what is the context for this answer, it looks like a code copy&pasted from somewhere. Can you extend it with some introduction, or description it may be?

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. - [From Review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/13223379)

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's `.find()` method for this like below:

```
if ( $( '.wrapper' ).find( $( e.target ) ).length > 0 ) {
    // target is a child of $( '.wrapper' )
}
```

```js
$( document ).on('click', function ( e ) {
    if ( $( '.wrapper' ).find( $( e.target ) ).length > 0 ) {
        // do staff here, target's inside $( '.wrapper' )
        alert( 'target is a child of .wrapper' );
    } else {
        alert( 'target is not a child of .wrapper' );
    }
} );
```

```css
.wrapper {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: black;
    display: flex;
}
.wrapper:before {
    content: '.wrapper';
    color: #FFF;
    position: absolute;
}
.child {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    background: red;
    margin: auto;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="child">.child</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you bind another event?

```
$('.wrapper *').click(function() {
    // will execute on childrens of .wrapper
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's [is](https://api.jquery.com/is/) function,

```
var target = $(this).attr("href");

if ($('a[href="'+target+'"]').is(('.wrapper > *') {
  //do soemthing
}
```

`'.wrapper > *'` is a css selection for the explicit first level children of `.wrapper`.  If you need any nested anchor element then  use `'.wrapper *'` instead