# Cannot use jquery.find div with pseudo-element inside

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors, pseudo-element, shadow-dom

I'm trying to detect if a click is targetting outside a specific div. For that, I bind click events to the whole document and test if the target is a child of my div, like this :

```
var _div = $('myselector');

document.bind('click touchstart', function (event) {
    if (_div.find(event.target).length === 0) {
        callback();
    }
});
```

It works fine in most cases, but in some it fails. The specific case of failure are target div with shadow DOM inside :

When I click in some area inside the div I have this *event.target* :

```
<div class="row btnActions">
::before
        <a class="link pull-left ng-binding" style="" ng-click="deleteAllFilters()">
           Supprimer
        </a>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-right ng-binding" ng-click="validate()">
            Valider
        </button>
::after
    </div>
```

which is effectively inside my *_div* element, but *_div.find(event.target)* returns empty array, and  when I try to ask for *_div.find('.btnActions')* it returns me this :

```
<div class="row btnActions">
        <a class="link pull-left ng-binding" style="" ng-click="deleteAllFilters()">
           Supprimer
        </a>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-right ng-binding" ng-click="validate()">
            Valider
        </button>
    </div>
```

The difference is that in the last there is no shadow DOM, so I think that jquery cannot find element with pseudo-elements inside. Anybody know how to make *_div.find(event.target)* returning something good ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a event handler which fires for each of your divs, I'd suggest using [jQuerys "on"](https://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of bind as you can select on which elements the handler should fire. This even works if you're dynamically adding divs to your document. Something like this:

```js
$(document).on('click touchstart', "div", function (event) {
    alert("Clicked " + $(event.target).closest("div").attr("id"));
});
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8e9mf4ca/) which demonstrate this.

If you still want to track **all** clicks on the document and want to decide inside the handler if the click was on the document or inside some div, you can use something like this:

```
$(document).on('click touchstart', function (event) {
    var div = $(event.target).closest("div");
    if (div.length > 0) {
        alert("Inside Div");   
    } else {
        alert("Outside Div");
    }
});
```

See [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8e9mf4ca/2/).

If you still want to define your selector beforehand (like your example), you could do something like this:

```
var _div = $("#div1");

$(document).on('click touchstart', function (event) {
    var target = $(event.target);

    if (_div.has(target).length || _div.is(target)) {
        alert("Inside Div1");   
    } else {
        alert("Outside Div1");
    }
});
```

In this case you need to check if the click happend to a child of your selector or is the selector itself (in case someone clicked directly on the div). See [here](https://jsfiddle.net/8e9mf4ca/4/),

In each case I think that [jQuerys "closest" API](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957017/jquery-if-target-is-child-of-wrapper-then-do-something) will be useful to you.

Hope I understood your problem correctly.